# Scraping Craiglist with BeautifulSoup and getting first image in each posting

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, craigslist

I am currently trying to scrape aviation data from craigslist. I have no problem getting all the info I want except the first image for each post. Here is my link:

https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/avo?hasPic=1

I have been able to get all images thanks to a different post on this site but I am having trouble figuring out how to get just the first image.

I am using bs4 and requests for this script. Here is what I have so far which gets every image:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

image_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_300x300.jpg'
r = requests.get('https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/avo?hasPic=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ids = [item['data-ids'].replace('1:','') for item in soup.select('.result-image[data-ids]', limit = 10)] 
images = [image_url.format(j) for i in ids for j in i.split(',')]
print(images)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

inzel

Comment: It looks as if you are storing the images in an array.  Try using images[0] to access only the first image of that array.

Comment: I have tried that but it only gives me the first image.. not the first for each posting. Im sure it has something to do with the way I am looping thru the images but Im not savvy enough to figure it out haha

Comment: @inzel do you want to have a list of each img on the url ?

Comment: Nope. I want to have a list of the first image in each post

Comment: @inzel have you checked the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find all class with the gallery of images then get the data-ids.
Then split them into a list and get the first element [0].

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

image_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_300x300.jpg'
r = requests.get('https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/avo?hasPic=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ids = [item.get('data-ids').replace('1:','') for item in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "result-image gallery"}, limit=10)] 
images = [image_url.format(i.split(',')[0]) for i in ids]
print(images)
```

Result:

['https://images.craigslist.org/00N0N_ci3cbcv5T58_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00101_5dLpBXXdDWJ_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00n0n_8zVXHONPkTH_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00l0l_jiNMe38avtl_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01212_fULyvfO9Rqz_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00D0D_ibbWWn7uFCu_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00z0z_2ylVbmdVnPr_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00Q0Q_ha0o2IJwj4Q_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01212_5LoZU43xA7r_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_7CMAu8vAhDi_300x300.jpg']

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what I was looking to do

Comment: If you like it, please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/avo?hasPic=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

img = "https://images.craigslist.org/"


imgs = [f"{img}{item.get('data-ids').split(':')[1].split(',')[0]}_300x300.jpg"
        for item in soup.findAll("a", class_="result-image gallery")]

print(imgs)
```

output:

```
['https://images.craigslist.org/00N0N_ci3cbcv5T58_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00101_5dLpBXXdDWJ_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00n0n_8zVXHONPkTH_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00l0l_jiNMe38avtl_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00q0q_l4hts9RPOuk_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00D0D_ibbWWn7uFCu_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00z0z_2ylVbmdVnPr_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00Q0Q_ha0o2IJwj4Q_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01212_5LoZU43xA7r_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_7CMAu8vAhDi_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00m0m_8c7azYhDR1Z_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00E0E_7k7cPL7zNnP_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00I0I_97AZy8UMt5V_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00G0G_iWw8AI8N8Kf_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00m0m_9BEEcvD0681_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01717_4Ut5FSIdoi3_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00h0h_jeAhtDXW2ST_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00T0T_hTogH4m9zTH_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01212_9x1EFI1CYHE_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00H0H_kiXLOtVgReA_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00P0P_ad77Eqvf1ul_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00909_jyBoTCNGmAJ_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00g0g_gFtJlANhi51_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00202_3LV7YERBssE_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00j0j_3zxT682nE2i_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00Y0Y_b6AXcApcSfl_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00M0M_6eTHo5E3Ee5_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00g0g_hvyvJKUejXY_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00I0I_d2WOWXtgQ8s_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00s0s_dAwJG0D6uce_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00g0g_TC2qvnD3AN_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00M0M_Dba39RfEkr_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00M0M_31drxF6c9vO_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00505_jOjMq3B8y0M_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00e0e_ixfV647qwLh_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00p0p_i2noTC4cADw_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00a0a_kywatxfm6Ud_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00808_1ZjIIX8PdaP_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01515_blEEDKbbyKD_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00b0b_brUn6sUxBzF_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_2ukBvcgvU99_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01212_dPTe5ZHM26A_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00B0B_1GsE81zVsr0_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00N0N_l8SXlBaI8lq_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00f0f_82qAzPq7cXd_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00w0w_lUrgFG9YOY0_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00C0C_kiZpgrFEnO8_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00T0T_g7IHvHMx14L_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00E0E_bzm9jRXpWVd_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00k0k_lOCRF1fgWCF_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00y0y_exwReppAi3L_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01515_7xyZ605hYcc_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_hqLMLvTCfXk_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00505_3P0xQrbeFY4_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00r0r_gj6dO6ZHO8L_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/01717_cIVmzgKCWtP_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00w0w_6O59k6qlZQz_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00808_jd43ZthN1uB_300x300.jpg', 'https://images.craigslist.org/00m0m_1GJ41cKvv4Y_300x300.jpg']
```

That list is containing the first image for each post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean and straightforward solution:

```py
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_image_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_300x300.jpg'
r = requests.get('https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/avo?hasPic=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

results = []
for elem in soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "result-image gallery"})[:2]:
    listing_url = elem.get("href")
    image_urls = []
    image_ids = elem.get("data-ids")
    if image_ids:
        image_urls = [base_image_url.format(curr_id[2:]) for curr_id in image_ids.split(",")]
    results.append((listing_url, image_urls))

pprint(results)
```

Output:

```py
[('https://spokane.craigslist.org/avo/d/spokane-lightspeed-sierra-headset/7090771925.html',
  ['https://images.craigslist.org/00N0N_ci3cbcv5T58_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00q0q_5ax4n1nCwmI_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00202_pAcLlJsaR3_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00z0z_kCZGUL6WZZw_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00G0G_8A2Xg7Wbe7B_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00f0f_cNpP8ZfUXdU_300x300.jpg']),
 ('https://spokane.craigslist.org/avo/d/spokane-window-mounted-air-conditioner/7090361383.html',
  ['https://images.craigslist.org/00101_5dLpBXXdDWJ_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00I0I_lxNKJsQAT7X_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00t0t_3BeBsNO6xH6_300x300.jpg',
   'https://images.craigslist.org/00L0L_aPnbejSiXQp_300x300.jpg'])]
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)